# Parsing concatenated json messages using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have 1 or more concatenated JSON messages I need to parse.
Each message is on its own, and I expect to receive only 1 on each read, but sometimes I get more. Since it's not a JSON array there are no `[]` around the messages.

Usually what i get is:

```
{"status": 0, "messageIndex": 0, "objs": [{"y": 0, "x": 0}, {"y": 0, "x": 0}], "count": 2}
```

But sometimes I get:

```
{"status": 0, "messageIndex": 0, "objs": [{"y": 0, "x": 0}, {"y": 0, "x": 0}], "count": 2}{"status": 0, "messageIndex": 1, "objs": [{"y": 0, "x": 0}, {"y": 0, "x": 0}], "count": 2}
```

Is this a valid Json structure? How can I parse this?

I'm using C# with Json.NET for parsing

Comment: It's not a valid JSON structure.

However, if messages do not contain any subobjects it should be fairly easy to parse those.

Comment: @jgauffin - My messages contain subobjects - edited the original message

Comment: You can use Regex that matches the JSON object and invoke the JSON parser/deserializer on each match. Instead of round parenthesis switch to curly brackets: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition

Comment: The best solution is of course is to tell those who send that information to do it correctly by wrapping it in an array. If that's not feasible, you need to pre-process it before deserializing it as JSON.

Comment: You're right - I've added a message wrapping protocol in the sending program, and a state machine in the client. So now I parse the Jsons message by message